# How is Java String hashCode calculated on objects

Tags: java, hashmap, hashcode

"Sun" and "TWO" gives the same hashCode() values in Java.

How come this outputs:

```
HashMap<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("Sun", 1);
System.out.println(map.get("TWO"));
```

outputs: null

but

```
HashMap<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("Sun".hashCode(), 1);
System.out.println(map.get("TWO".hashCode()));
```

outputs: 1

Isnt hashmap calling hashCode() on the string "Sun" to use it as a key?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When an object is inserted into a `HashMap`, it does use the `hashCode` method to decide where to store it. But `hashCode`s aren't intended to be completely unique. There can be different values that produce the same output but aren't equal, so the `HashMap` will have some method of dealing with collisions like that. `get` will only return a value if the keys have both the same `hashCode`, and are equal using the `equals` method. `"Sun"` does not equal `"TWO"`, but the hashCode of `"Sun"` *does* equal the hashCode of `"TWO"`.

From [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#get-java.lang.Object-):

> if this map contains a mapping from a key k to a value v such that (key==null ? k==null : key.equals(k)), then this method returns v; otherwise it returns null. (There can be at most one such mapping.)

So it's equality, not the hashcode, that determines what gets returned. The hashcode is effectively just an optimization to make the process of finding which objects are likely to be equal much faster.